# Pass String into SQL Query from Textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Background**

I've written a function that retrieves data using a SQL query and then outputs that data to a label. At the moment the search string is hard coded to "1002". The function is fired on a button click event.

**Question**

How do I pass data into my SQL query from a textbox so my search string is the contents of the text box, instead of 1002?

**Code**

```
private void getInfoStationID()
{
    String ConnStr = "Data Source=SqlServer; Initial Catalog=Database; User ID=Username; Password=Password";
    String SQL = "SELECT stationname FROM dbo.Stations WHERE StationID = 1002";

    SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, ConnStr);
    DataSet question = new DataSet();
    Adpt.Fill(question);

    foreach (DataRow dr in question.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        nameTtb.Text += question.Tables[0].Rows[0]["stationname"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at parameterized queries and `SqlCommand`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the query to:

```
string constring = @""; // Declare your connection string here.

String SQL = "SELECT stationname FROM dbo.Stations WHERE StationID = @StationId";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
con.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL ,con);
```

and then you have to add parameter to the command object like this:

```
command .Parameters.Add("@StationId",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textbox.Text;
```

Now you might be wondering why I have used parameters in the query. It is to avoid SQL Injection.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adb = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
adb.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
```

And now you can iterate like this...

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{

}
```

And you have to initialise the connection object and pass your connection string in it.

Comment: Great answer with explanations! Explaining what is actually happening really helps when you are learning a new language. Thank you.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Sorry man...i thought that ConnStr  is a SqlConnection Object...hold for a sec

Comment: Nope connStr is my connection string. :) Okay thank you,

Comment: And i think that you have also not opened the sqlconnection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69526/discussion-between-mudit-juneja-and-dan-cundy).

Comment: Do i need to pass the var in through the function header?

Answer (score 0):

```
String ConnStr = "Data Source=SqlServer; Initial Catalog=Database; User ID=Username; Password=Password";
string SQL = "SELECT stationname FROM dbo.Stations WHERE StationID = @stationID";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, ConnStr);

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stationID", SqlDbType.Int));
command.Parameters["@stationID"].Value = textbox.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your SQL string to use a variable, like @StationID, then add the variable to the query from textbox.text

```
String SQL = "SELECT stationname FROM dbo.Stations WHERE StationID = @StationID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand;
cmd.CommandText = SQL;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = ConnStr;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StationID", Textbox1.Text);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet nds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(nds);
```

Comment: [Don't use AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).